# How do I convert - and , delimited string into tabular format in R?

Tags: r

My string is like this:

```
2 cups - Desiccated Coconut, 2.5 cups - Maida, 1.25 cup - Butter, 1/2 tsp - Baking soda, 1.25 cup - Powdered Sugar, 1/2 tsp - Baking powder, 2-3 drops - Vanilla essence
```

I want the output in the following format:

[image: Click here]

Comment: I want the output as R table.

Comment: Hint: Split on comma, transpose, then split on dash, then split on space, then add column names... show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, you just need to finally give correct names to variables.
Next time, please demonstrate you tried something or investigated a little bit more. You will need package `stringr` for that to remove trailing and leading spaces.

```
txt= c("2 cups - Desiccated Coconut, 2.5 cups - Maida, 1.25 cup - Butter, 1/2 tsp - Baking soda, 1.25 cup - Powdered Sugar, 1/2 tsp - Baking powder, 2-3 drops - Vanilla essence")
splits_per_ingredients = strsplit(txt,c(","))[[1]]
split_per_quantity = sapply(splits_per_ingredients,strsplit," - ")
split_per_dose=t(sapply(split_per_quantity,FUN=function(vec) {c(strsplit(stringr::str_trim(vec[1])," ")[[1]],vec[2])}))
```

Output:

```
                              [,1]   [,2]    [,3]                
 2 cups - Desiccated Coconut  "2"    "cups"  "Desiccated Coconut"
  2.5 cups - Maida            "2.5"  "cups"  "Maida"             
  1.25 cup - Butter           "1.25" "cup"   "Butter"            
  1/2 tsp - Baking soda       "1/2"  "tsp"   "Baking soda"       
  1.25 cup - Powdered Sugar   "1.25" "cup"   "Powdered Sugar"    
  1/2 tsp - Baking powder     "1/2"  "tsp"   "Baking powder"     
  2-3 drops - Vanilla essence "2-3"  "drops" "Vanilla essence"
```

Comment: Thanks dude :) You saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> library(stringr)
> 
> str = '2 cups - Desiccated Coconut, 2.5 cups - Maida, 1.25 cup - Butter, 1/2 tsp - Baking soda, 1.25 cup - Powdered Sugar, 1/2 tsp - Baking powder, 2-3 drops - Vanilla essence'
> 
> df = data.frame(Qty = unlist(strsplit(str, ',')))
> df
                           Qty
1  2 cups - Desiccated Coconut
2             2.5 cups - Maida
3            1.25 cup - Butter
4        1/2 tsp - Baking soda
5    1.25 cup - Powdered Sugar
6      1/2 tsp - Baking powder
7  2-3 drops - Vanilla essence
> 
> df = df %>% separate(Qty, c('Unit', 'Ingredient'), ' - ')
> df
        Unit         Ingredient
1     2 cups Desiccated Coconut
2   2.5 cups              Maida
3   1.25 cup             Butter
4    1/2 tsp        Baking soda
5   1.25 cup     Powdered Sugar
6    1/2 tsp      Baking powder
7  2-3 drops    Vanilla essence
> 
> # remove start & end white spaces (stringr library)
> # or else you can't separate correctly
> df$Unit = str_trim(df$Unit)
> df = df %>% separate(Unit, c('Qty', 'Unit'), ' ')
> df
   Qty  Unit         Ingredient
1    2  cups Desiccated Coconut
2  2.5  cups              Maida
3 1.25   cup             Butter
4  1/2   tsp        Baking soda
5 1.25   cup     Powdered Sugar
6  1/2   tsp      Baking powder
7  2-3 drops    Vanilla essence
```